How to solve ERROR: operator is not unique: "unknown" - "unknown" in a dynamic SQL query?
I have a execute block inside a stored procedure and I am executing a query dynamically:
execute 'create table raw_mine.financial_multicase_xwalk_' || target_date || '
as
select distinct
  a.cvr_mnth_dt
, a.filler_string_10
, a.alt_prsn_id
, a.member_id
from raw_mine.rstag_mine_TO_CGT_MBRSHP_' || target_date || ' a
left join
raw_mine.rstag_mine_TO_CGT_FIN_' || target_date || ' b
on a.filler_string_10 = b.filler_string_10
and a.member_id = b.member_id
and left ( a.cvr_mnth_dt, 6) = left ( b.cvr_mnth_dt, 6)
left join
raw_mine.rstag_mine_TO_CGT_FIN_' || target_date || ' cp
on a.filler_string_10 = cp.filler_string_10
and a.alt_prsn_id = cp.alt_prsn_id
and left ( a.cvr_mnth_dt, 6) = left ( cp.cvr_mnth_dt, 6)
left join
raw_mine.member_xwalk_dulality_' || target_date || ' c
on a.alt_prsn_id = c.alt_prsn_id
and left ( a.cvr_mnth_dt, 6) = left ( replace ( c.cvr_mnth_dt, '-', ''), 6)
where nullif ( c.alt_prsn_id, '') is null
and cp.alt_prsn_id is not null
and cp.member_id != a.member_id;';

all the columns are varchars and target_date is input param from the procedure and I am getting an error

SQL Error [42725]: ERROR: operator is not unique: "unknown" - "unknown"
Hint: Could not choose a best candidate operator. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Any idea how to solve this?
This query works while executing outside the procedure.

It looks like you've forgotten to escape the single quotes defining strings in these lines:
and left ( a.cvr_mnth_dt, 6) = left ( replace ( c.cvr_mnth_dt, '-', ''), 6)
where nullif ( c.alt_prsn_id, '') is null

You will probably want
and left ( a.cvr_mnth_dt, 6) = left ( replace ( c.cvr_mnth_dt, ''-'', ''''), 6)
where nullif ( c.alt_prsn_id, '''') is null

